# APEX Custom webservice - record limit

Tags: integration

I need to develop a custom web service but wanted to know the total# records I can send in one call? Is it 200 records like the SOAP API or any limit? This is update operation into salesforce.

This is the high-level code.

```
global class MyWebService {    
webService static void makeContact(List<Contact> Contacts) {  
      }
}  //comment to let code be formatted
```

Would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks/Chandra

Answer (score 4):

You're only limited by the size of your request.

The maximum request size is 3mb. This is covered under the [Static Apex Limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#static_gov_limits_section).

Obviously you need to keep within any other Apex limits within your method, but in terms of incoming data all you need to worry about is the request size.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex said you will need to worry on the 3MB size limit of the request body

> Since the SOAP custom Services are developed using apex following limits that are applicable to apex will apply

1)You wont be able to insert more than 10000  rows of contact since only 10000 rows you can insert in single call

2)You wont be able to query more than 50K rows in your method

3)You wont be able to do more than 100 SOQL in single context.

If you have large chunk of data ,then call this method in multiple batches .

Also as a best practice of design ensure you are developing this because standard REST API of salesforce were not helpful to you and you want to do some transformation of data once data is inside SFDC .

Comment: THis is SOAP web service not REST but I got your point. Thanks.